# d3.js Rearranging columns of data for plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I've been trying for a while but I am unsure of what keyword I need to search for. Anyways, I am interested in changing how the data in d3 is loaded so I can rearrange columns in plots. In R terms, what I am looking for would be about the equivalent of changing factor levels to be able to rearrange columns in a bar plot.

For example, in the link to a block below, I want to manually set which order the parallel coordinates are. Currently, it shows economy, cylinders, to year left to right. I want to do something like year, weight, displacement, etc.

https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281

Comment: Do you notice that you can manually drag the columns?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to have certain presets in specific locations such as having year at the far left and let the user change around as they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the columns is determined by `d3.keys(cars[0])` in this snippet:

```
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) {
            return +p[d];
        }))
        .range([height, 0]));
}));
```

For instance, here is the same code, but using...

```
d3.keys(cars[0]).sort()
```

... to sort the array alphabetically: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9fb7329fed0e2ea539bab5bc5a47a16c

So, if you want a specific order, you can simply pass the desired array:

```
x.domain(dimensions = ["year", , "weight (lb)", "name", "displacement (cc)", "economy (mpg)", "cylinders", "power (hp)", "0-60 mph (s)"].filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) {
            return +p[d];
        }))
        .range([height, 0]));
}));
```

Here is the blocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/4f1798a5e658df7986f70effa030497c

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can take the csv file (i.e cars.csv) and edit in excel spreadsheet. There you can transpose the column as you wish and copy back to your d3js function. Look at the example below (Done with excel):

```
name,year,weight (lb),displacement (cc),economy (mpg),cylinders,power (hp),0-60 mph (s)
```

AMC Ambassador Brougham,73,3821,360,13,8,175,11
AMC Ambassador DPL,70,3850,390,15,8,190,8.5
AMC Ambassador SST,72,3672,304,17,8,150,11.5
AMC Concord DL 6,79,3265,232,20.2,6,90,18.2

Etc... I didn't want it to extend too much...